# Ubuntu doesn't support USB wifi card in LiveCD mode - any way i can fix this?

Tags: networking, drivers, live-cd

Been trying to test out Ubuntu in livecd mode, hoping to install it but whenever im in livecd mode my USB wifi card simply just isn't supported. everything else seems to work, but just not the wifi.  I use a TP-Link Archer T4UH v2 if thats any help. anyone know how I could get it to work? really want to start using ubuntu

--There are some "Linux" drivers on the TPLink website, but it's all just source code and hasnt been updated since 2018. don't wanna go down the route of compiling my own drivers, looks like an absolute nightmare

edit: just gonna buy a new wifi thing. :P

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1354230/edit) and add the new information.

Comment: There are very few USB wireless devices that we can't coax to life. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

1. run udevadm monitor, plugin the device and check for errors.
2. compiling is usually a matter of running make and make install